# Frequent BSODs on Dell notebook with different error messages

Tags: windows-10, backup, bsod, crash

Since this morning I get one blue screen after another on my Dell XPS 13 9360 with Windows 10. I get a variety of different error messages, the first one was:

SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED

and the file Wdf01000.sys was mentioned as well. After this I managed to get into my OS again and searched for a fix. The first suggestion was to type `sfc /scannow` in the command promt, which I did (with Administrator permission). The result was the next immediate blue screen. This time with the message:

DRIVER_IRQL... I did not manage to write up the rest, because I unplugged the monitor, and then everything went black, but I believe it was something like DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL.

After several reboots I got a blue screen with the message:

KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE

Then finally the Dell support assistant intervened on the next restart and I did a full check. No hardware problems found, when checking the OS the error

OS_BOOT_FAILURE

was issued, but the support assistant could not find anything to fix. It then suggested to do a full system recovery which would delete all my personal files. I absolutely do not want that to happen, I have a backup, but it is a few weeks old, I don't want to lose my data if it is anyhow possible.

Whenever I make it into the OS, the system crashes after some time, no matter what I do, this time always with the error message

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

and the causing file is supposed to be fvevol.sys.

I believe that the cause is a **windows update**, since yesterday (or the day before?) when I shut down my laptop something had to be updated before.

How do I fix this without losing my data? I don't know how much I can do from the OS directly since it crashes frequently. The time window is definitely too short to do a meaningful backup.

Edit1:  I just saw that a windows update is ready to be installed (KB4497165). Would it be a good idea to install it now and see what happens?

Edit2: I am now sure that the crash happens after some time without me doing anything. This time with the error message

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL,

and causing file: afd.sys.

Comment: I would run memory and hardware tests from the bios.>>>>>https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln115162/resolve-hardware-issues-with-built-in-and-online-diagnostics-supportassist-epsa-epsa-or-psa-error-codes?lang=en#How

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully i can be of some help

> Explanation of error

"The most common cause of this error is an incorrect or corrupted pointer that references an incorrect location in memory."

In english, something didn't install correctly or a driver had a hissy fit and said "Well, i'm not gonna work know", thats the most common problem anyway. It can sometimes be a system service, even anti-virus, or a backup tool. In other cases it can be cpu overheating. I've seen a few times people say the get "Bsod" and its because their laptop is on a cushion and cant get any air and over heats. Or at the worse end, which isn't an often problem your ram or motherboard has decided it doesn't like functioning

> Possible Solution

You stated after some time you can get into the windows system the error shows. If this means you have a brief window of opportunity i would suggest following this.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4028391/windows-how-to-fix-error-0xa-irqlnotlessorequal

If this however doesn't help you Restart your pc and press "f8" in the loading window or boot window to bring up advanced start-up options and go into safe mode.

Once you've booted into safe mode, you can go to device manager and check on your drivers see if they are all okay.

Check your installed programs. Do you see one you've not seen before, suspicious program appeared from no where?

There is some helpfull guides here that could assist you in solving your problem as well
https://www.minitool.com/backup-tips/irql-not-less-or-equal-windows-10-021.html

Comment: There were some updates to install, I managed to do that. Now I can enter the OS more consistently, but it still crashes after some time. The second option unfortunately does not work because I get a blue screen whenever I try to enter safe mode.

Comment: It seems that rolling back the last windows update did the trick. Still, I will take a close look at my drivers. Since you were helpful, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @And Fair enough thank you very much. Normally i always start with a roll back if possible. Glad i could be of some kind of help :) Good ol windows ... breaks its self on update XD