# Fixed Computer with Windows update rollback - what now?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, cpu-usage

I was able to "fix" my Laptop, which showed blue screens all the time - see this question: [Frequent BSODs on Dell notebook with different error messages](https://superuser.com/questions/1561566/frequent-bsods-on-dell-notebook-with-different-error-messages) - by rolling back the last **security update** by windows. Now the OS works again, but everything is really **slow**. Task manager frequently shows a CPU useage of > 70 %, sometimes even > 90 %, although I don't have processes running that should cause it. Windows defender says that my laptop is secure.

Clearly, something is not right. My first guess is, that I should check for windows updates, since those also contain relevant drivers and so on, but the last windows update caused my problems. On the other hand I cannot postpone updates forever either. So how do I proceed? I am doing a full backup now, what else can I do to prepare my system for the next updates/steps? The RAM usage is pretty normal around 40 %.

Edit: When the CPU usage is really high, it is caused by "Systemunterbrechungen".

Comment: do you have any third-party antivirus installed? they may drastically slow down your system.

Comment: No, I only use the Windows Defender.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of chicken and egg problem. You had drivers running "fast" but creating blue screens. By restoring probably you have earlier drivers version which don't crash but manages poorly HW interrupts.
What you can do is to try to update the drivers one by one until you see the System interrupts CPU consumption drops but you might get again the blue screens. A least you might locate which "new" driver starts to create the issues...
See more here: [High CPU usage for System interrupts](https://www.howtogeek.com/271400/what-is-the-system-interrupts-process-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-pc/)